# programmatically bind mouse events mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, mouseevent, viewmodel, mousedown

I have a `dll` which adds/removes `Canvases`, and deals with drawing on them.

I wish to "register" each `Canvas` I add to `MouseMove`, `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.

I know I can add those 3 event functions and do it the traditional way, but I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way of doing that in `MVVM`?

I tried to search for it, but found only implementation of it in the `xaml` using `Interactivity`.

Comment: Do it in the code-behind of the view. Remember, this is **view code**, and therefore should be in the view, not the view model.

Comment: But then again, if those events affect anything else besides view, you do want to e.g. delegate/bind events to VM...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this but in my experience you'll save yourself a lot of work by creating a Blend behavior. Start by declaring an interface you can use to communicate with your view model, here's a very simple one:

```
public interface IMouseCaptureProxy
{
    event EventHandler Capture;
    event EventHandler Release;

    void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
    void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
    void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseCaptureArgs e);
}

public class MouseCaptureArgs
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public bool LeftButton { get; set; }
    public bool RightButton { get; set; }
}
```

Then the behavior itself:

```
public class MouseCaptureBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProxyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Proxy",
        typeof(IMouseCaptureProxy),
        typeof(MouseCaptureBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnProxyChanged));

    public static void SetProxy(DependencyObject source, IMouseCaptureProxy value)
    {
        source.SetValue(ProxyProperty, value);
    }

    public static IMouseCaptureProxy GetProxy(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (IMouseCaptureProxy)source.GetValue(ProxyProperty);
    }

    private static void OnProxyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue is IMouseCaptureProxy)
        {
            (e.OldValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Capture -= OnCapture;
            (e.OldValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Release -= OnRelease;
        }
        if (e.NewValue is IMouseCaptureProxy)
        {
            (e.NewValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Capture += OnCapture;
            (e.NewValue as IMouseCaptureProxy).Release += OnRelease;
        }
    }

    static void OnCapture(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = sender as MouseCaptureBehavior;
        if (behavior != null)
            behavior.AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
    }

    static void OnRelease(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = sender as MouseCaptureBehavior;
        if (behavior != null)
            behavior.AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += OnMouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += OnMouseUp;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= OnMouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove -= OnMouseMove;
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= OnMouseUp;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseDown(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseMove(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy(this);
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);
            var args = new MouseCaptureArgs
            {
                X = pos.X,
                Y = pos.Y,
                LeftButton = (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed),
                RightButton = (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            };
            proxy.OnMouseUp(this, args);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you just add it to whichever control you want mouse event notification on:

```
                    <Canvas>
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:MouseCaptureBehavior Proxy="{Binding}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

In this case I'm binding Proxy to the DataContext, which happens to be a MainViewModel, so make sure MainViewModel inherits IMouseCaptureProxy. Then it's a simple matter of implementing the various handlers and the Capture/Release handlers which you can then raise to capture and release the mouse, should you need to:

```
    public event EventHandler Capture;
    public event EventHandler Release;

    public void OnMouseDownobject sender, MouseCaptureArgs e)
    {
        this.Capture(sender, null);
        // etc
    }
```

Some would argue that passing sender into the handlers is technically a violation of MVVM, and personally I'd say I probably agree with this, but this should at least be enough to get you started. If you're an MVVM purist then you'll want to modify the behaviour to instead create intermediate objects that track that kind of thing internally.